# Disable PostgreSQL trigger while running the maintenance task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, background-process

I have simple maintenance like below:

```rb
module Maintenance
  class UpdateOrderCount < MaintenanceTasks::Task
    def collection
      Order.all
    end

    def process(element)
      element.update(accepted_quantity: element.quantity)
    end
  end
end
```

However, we also have a trigger listening any updates of `orders` table.

Assuming such a thing is possible, what would be the best way to disable this trigger for each update coming from the task above, but keep the trigger for updates that does happen else where?

Comment: The trigger itself will be enabled or disabled. The trigger function that is used by this trigger, could have some logic to decide what to do when. You could use a different database user for your maintenance and use this attribute for your logic.